# Angular: Not able to display data from firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to create a simple todo application from a tutorial. I'm trying to use ng-repeat for displaying values from firebase into a table. Not able to retrieve the values for "todo.activity" and "todo.notes".This is my code so far.

---

[todo.html](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/janapanaramsai/b28a76ffb47bffda9021b8587f3b4602/raw/77501c3ee3d7ec2877962246ee8d7398308168dc/todo.html)

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h3>Add an activity</h3>
        <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="activity">Activity</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="activity" ng-model="activity" placeholder="activity">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="notes" ng-model="notes" placeholder="activity">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <h3>Todo List</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Activity</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                <td>{{todo.activity}}</td>
                <td>{{todo.notes}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

[todo.js](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/janapanaramsai/b28a76ffb47bffda9021b8587f3b4602/raw/77501c3ee3d7ec2877962246ee8d7398308168dc/todo.js)

```
'use strict';
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyAfjQC4qL7tMu37XA2z469jfLCrsMsHdAM",
      authDomain: "todo-5a1c3.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://todo-5a1c3.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "todo-5a1c3.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "636959211631"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
angular.module('myApp.todo', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/todo', {
    templateUrl: 'todo/todo.html',
    controller: 'TodoCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray',function($scope,$firebaseArray) {

  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  $scope.todos = $firebaseArray(rootRef.child('todos'));
  $scope.addTodo = function(){
    console.log("adding contact");

    $scope.todos.$add({
      activity: $scope.activity,
      notes   : $scope.notes
    }).then(function(rootRef){
      var id = rootRef.key;
      console.log('Added Contant '+id);
      $scope.activity = '';
      $scope.notes = '';
    });
  }

}]);
```

Comment: You need to at least provide us some information to help you out.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee hey sorry for the ambiguity, I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase, using `{{todo.activity}}` and `{{todo.notes}}` inside a table using `ng-repeat`

Comment: In the HTML, your table row for the data is closed with the cells outside of the row.  This isn't semantically correct.  Review that area of the HTML and see if that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your html for the ng-repeat is incorrect. It should be something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <td>{{todo.activity}}</td>
        <td>{{todo.notes}}</td>             
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Sorry ,edited the <tr> tag but does not work either